# Error: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key y

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

This observer works well

```
[self.tableView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

But this one produce an error.

```
[self.tableView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset.y" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];

 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSConcreteValue 0x6e3eda0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key y.'
```

But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because although `contentOffset` exists as a property in your class, it is in fact an instance of a `CGPoint`, which is just a regular C structure, not an Objective-C class and hence is not KVC compliant.

In the second example you're treating it like an Objective-C class.

**Update**

It might be slightly confusing, but going back to your example:

```
self.contentOffset       // contentOffset is a property of the current class
self.contentOffset.y     // y is a member of the CGPoint structure of which contentOffset is an instance
```

The two look the same, but one is Objective-C style and the other is C-style. C `struct`s predate Objective-C and do not implement KVC. Remember that Objective-C is built on top of C, so everything that is in C is also in Objective-C, but the reverse does not apply. 
Accessing an Objective-C class property just happens to have the same syntax as accessing a member of a struct.

You're probably subclassing `UIScrollView` and if you check the appropriate header file, you'll probably see something like

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint contentOffset;
```

The `assign` means it's a C data type. Also note the lack of a `*` that would indicate a pointer.

The declaration of `CGPoint` also confirms that it is not an Objective-C class:

```
struct CGPoint {
  CGFloat x;
  CGFloat y;
};
typedef struct CGPoint CGPoint;
```

As you can see, `CGPoint` is not derived from `NSObject`.

Comment: As far as I understand if we use dot syntax we need that contentOffset was inherited from NSObject. Am I right?

Comment: @Voloda2 KVO relies on creating subclasses of an NSObject at runtime. These subclasses override the setter methods for properties, and post notifications when the setter is called. 

structs do not have setter methods so there is no way to inject these notifications, it is the same result as if you modify an instance variable directly: there will be no KVO notifications in that case